# ClientScript not available in a method class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class that have this method for search. My problem is, A class does not support Client Script. It will only work if I place it in a Web Page. Help! What is the other way to do it. Btw, I will call this Method on my web Page.

```
 public void SearchAffectedUser()
    {
      //some code here

    if (dr.Read())
      {
        //some code here

      }
   else
     {
      this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Record Not Found. Please try again');</script>");
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can return `boolean` value from this method to the website's caller method,

```
public void SearchAffectedUser()
    {
    if (dr.Read())
      {
         //return true ;   
      }
   else
     {
       //return false;
     }
```

on the basis of `boolean` you can show the popup.

Comment: then when Ill have a condition like this if(SearchAffectedUser == true)??

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `Page` object to that method:

```
public void SearchAffectedUser(Page page)
{
  //some code here
  if (dr.Read())
  {
      //some code here
  }
  else
  {
      page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Record Not Found. Please try again');</script>");
  }
}
```

but in my opinion it is not best approach. I'd do it like that: create method that do some job and return a value (may be bool or something more complicated) and handle registering script inside your page class methods.

```
public bool SearchAffectedUser(Page page)
{
  //some code here
  if (dr.Read())
  {
      //some code here
  }
  else
  {
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

//inside your Page class
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EvetArgs e)
{
   //logic
   if (!obj.SearchAffectedUser())
   {
      this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScript", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Record Not Found. Please try again');</script>");
   }
}
```

of course this is only markup but I hope you see what I'm trying to show here :)

Answer (score 0):

ClientScript belongs to the Page class. Because web forms are derived from Page class you find it there.

Firstly, if this is just a business layer class, it is not a good idea to have the web references in this project. If only you derive this class from Page class, then you will be able to use ClientScript.